Leetcode issue with Memory Limit Exceeded
I recently started leetcode and ive been getting better.  I attempted a problem and i got through all 479/485 test cases. But my code is struggling with a large set of data.
I tried completing the code on my own, and it works good on small sets.  Can somebody explain to me how I can make it more efficient with large sets of data, and what makes mine struggle.
Here is the Question: A phrase is a palindrome if, after converting all uppercase letters into lowercase letters and removing all non-alphanumeric characters, it reads the same forward and backward. Alphanumeric characters include letters and numbers.
Given a string s, return true if it is a palindrome, or false otherwise.
Here is my code:
class Solution {
public:
    bool isPalindrome(string s) {
        string noSpaceString = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
            s[i] = tolower(s[i]);

            if((int(s[i]) >= 97 && int(s[i]) <= 122) || (int(s[i]) >= 48 && int(s[i] <= 57)))
            {
                noSpaceString = noSpaceString + s[i]; 
            }
        }

        string reverseStr = noSpaceString; 
        reverse(reverseStr.begin(), reverseStr.end());

        if(noSpaceString == reverseStr)
             return true;
        else 
             return false;
    }
};


You don't need 2 strings or reversing to tell if its a palindrome. Your code actually has 3 strings when you need  just 1.

Did you ask this question on the LeetCode forums?  If so, could you include a link to that question here, so we can read the responses there?  If not, why not?

When I think further on the problem you should be able to do this with 1 pass through s which doesn't even need to modify s you can do a case insensitive comparison of just the alphanumeric characters skipping the rest.

You can complete this task by only using the initial string s. Just scan simultaneously forward and backwards in that string, skipping spaces and converting case as you go. If your forward and backward scans ever don't match it's not a palindrome, if they meet in the middle it is.

Side note: don't hard-code values to test for letters and digits; the standard library has code to do that, and it's both more portable and faster. Read about std::isalpha.

FYI, when comparing characters or letters to constants, use the literal notation, i.e. 'A'.  This is much more readable then decimal 65 (I have to convert to hex to find out the actual letter).  Also, there may be different encodings where 65 != 'A'.


Memory Limit Exceeded
Can somebody explain to me how I can make it more efficient with large sets of data, and what makes mine struggle.

The code in the OP exceeds the memory limit because it unnecessarily makes two copies of the original string.

noSpaceString copies the original string while skipping over non-alphanumeric characters.
reverseStr is initialized by copying noSpaceString

The code uses more memory than those copies suggest, because, for large strings, the loop that creates variable noSpaceString will trigger reallocations as the string grows. Those could be eliminated by calling member function reserve.
std::string noSpaceString;
noSpaceString.reserve(s.length());

The code in the OP is also unnecessarily slow.

Making copies takes time.
The call to std::reverse iterates through half of the string, as it swaps characters from the front to the rear.

In addition, the OP uses the following test to detect alphanumeric characters:
if((int(s[i]) >= 97 && int(s[i]) <= 122) || (int(s[i]) >= 48 && int(s[i] <= 57)))
{
    // ...
}

This test is slower than using std::isalnum, which is typically implemented using a lookup table. Furthermore, the test in the OP depends on ASCII character values, and will fail on systems that use an incompatbile character set.
Although it won't have a significant impact on runtime, the following construct is needlessly complex:
if(noSpaceString == reverseStr)
        return true;
else 
        return false;

It can be replaced by:
return noSpaceString == reverseStr;

The comparison, however, is inefficient. It is only necessary to compare the first half of noSpaceString against the first half of reverseStr to determine whether you have a palindrome. Comparing the full strings slows things down a bit more.
Using std::erase_if and std::equal
Avoiding the copies is how you reduce the memory footprint, and speed things up.
The following solution uses std::erase_if to erase all non-alphanumeric characters from the original string s. It does this "in place," without making a copy.
std::erase_if(s, [](unsigned char c) { return !std::isalnum(c); });

Note that the lambda accepts an unsigned char argument by value. This has the effect of converting the characters in string s from type char to type unsigned char. The conversion is important, because the parameter to std::isalnum has type int. If you pass in a regular char (or a signed char), you will get into trouble if a character has a negative value. The negative values play havoc with the lookup tables, which are expecting positive indexes. See this note at CppReference.
After the erasure, std::equal provides an efficient and consise way to determine if the remaining characters form a palindrome. The trick is to compare a forward iterator against a reverse iterator, and stop when you get halfway through string s. Once again, note that the arguments to the comparison lambda are unsigned char. That way, they can be reliably used as arguments to std::tolower.
class Solution {
public:
    bool isPalindrome(string s) {
        enum : std::size_t { two = 2u };
        std::erase_if(s, [](unsigned char c) { return !std::isalnum(c); });
        return std::equal(
            s.cbegin(),                    // forward iterator
            s.cbegin() + s.size() / two,   // stop halfway through string `s`
            s.crbegin(),                   // reverse iterator
            [](unsigned char a, unsigned char b)
            { return std::tolower(a) == std::tolower(b); }
        );
    }
};

Parse string s without making any copies
As an alternative, you can run a loop to make the checks without calling std::equal. This solution treats short strings, with lengths below 2, as special cases. They are always palindromes. With those out of the way, you can set subscripts i and j at opposite ends of the string, and march them towards the middle. At each step, advance i and j until they land on an alphanumeric character. Then, compare the two characters. If they do not match, then string s is not a palindrome. Otherwise, if they do match, keep looping. When i and j cross, then you have found a palindrome.
class Solution {
public:
    bool isPalindrome(string s)
    {
        enum : std::size_t { one = 1u };
        if (s.size() <= one)
            return true;
        std::size_t i{};
        std::size_t j{ s.size() - one };
        for (;;)
        {
            while (i < s.size() && !std::isalnum(static_cast<unsigned char>(s[i])))
                ++i;
            while (j > i && !std::isalnum(static_cast<unsigned char>(s[j])))
                --j;
            if (i >= j) return true;
            auto const a{ std::tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(s[i])) };
            auto const b{ std::tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(s[j])) };
            if (a != b) return false;
            ++i; --j;
        }
        std::unreachable();
    }
};

Test program
Here is the program I used to test these two solutions. It uses modules, and compiles under C++23 (language standard: /std:c++latest). If desired, you can convert it to other versions of C++. import std; and std::unreachable are the only things used from C++23.
// LeetCode_0125_Valid_Palindrome.ixx
export module LeetCode_0125_Valid_Palindrome;
import std;

// This using declaration allows the LeetCode Solution 
// to be used without modifying its function signature.
// 
// (Shame on you, LeetCode, for teaching programmers to 
// rely on `using namespace std;`.)
using std::string;

class Solution {
public:
#if 1
    bool isPalindrome(string s)
    {
        enum : std::size_t { zero, one };
        if (s.size() <= one)
            return true;
        std::size_t i{};
        std::size_t j{ s.size() - one };
        for (;;)
        {
            while (i < s.size() && !std::isalnum(static_cast<unsigned char>(s[i])))
                ++i;
            while (j > i && !std::isalnum(static_cast<unsigned char>(s[j])))
                --j;
            if (i >= j) return true;
            auto const a{ std::tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(s[i])) };
            auto const b{ std::tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(s[j])) };
            if (a != b) return false;
            ++i; --j;
        }
        std::unreachable();
    }
#else
    bool isPalindrome(string s) {
        enum : std::size_t { two = 2u };
        std::erase_if(s, [](unsigned char c) { return !std::isalnum(c); });
        return std::equal(
            s.cbegin(),
            s.cbegin() + s.size() / two,
            s.crbegin(),
            [](unsigned char a, unsigned char b)
            { return std::tolower(a) == std::tolower(b); }
        );
    }
#endif
};
void solve(
    std::string_view heading,
    std::string s)
{
    std::cout << std::format(
        "{}"
        "\n"
        "\n  Input: {}"
        "\n  Output: {}"
        "\n\n"
        , heading, '"' + s + '"', Solution{}.isPalindrome(s)
    );
}
export bool LeetCode_0125_Valid_Palindrome()
{
    std::cout << "LeetCode 125. Valid Palindrome"
        "\nhttps://leetcode.com/problems/valid-palindrome/description/"
        "\n\n";
    solve("Example 1", "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama");
    solve("Example 2", "race a car");
    solve("Example 3", " ");
    solve("Example 4", "");
    solve("Example 5", "#a");
    solve("Example 6", "#aa");
    solve("Example 7", "##a");
    solve("Example 8", "##aa");
    solve("Example 9", "#a##");
    solve("Example 10", "#aa##");
    solve("Example 11", "#a#");
    solve("Example 12", "#a#a");
    return true;
}
// LeetCode_0125_Valid_Palindrome.ixx


So there is no need to copy strings.
You are already creating a copy the way you passing the string to the method. (compiler probably optimizes that out in your version)
A good practice is to consult the standard algorithms to see if they can be applied. A significant number of loops can be replaced with standard algorithms.
In the example below(which most closely resembles yours without the memory issue) remove_if and transform are used.
Named lambdas are also introduced, which is a great way to utilize the standard algorithms.
    #include <string> 
    #include <algorithm>  
    #include <cctype>
    
    using namespace std; 
    
    class Solution {
    public:
    //not using reference for s as this function is destructive
        bool isPalindrome(string s) {
            string noSpaceString = "";
    
            auto notAlNum = [] (unsigned char c) {return !isalnum(c);}; // lambda looking for non-alphanumeric
            s.erase(remove_if(s.begin(),s.end(),notAlNum),s.end()); //remove characters
 
            auto transformToLower = [](unsigned char c){ return std::tolower(c); };
            transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), transformToLower);
            if(0 == s.size()) return true;
            auto end = s.size()-1;
            for(auto i=0u;i<end && (i<=(end-i));++i){
                if(s[i]!=s[end-i]) return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

If you were concerned with the fact that you now loop twice before doing your compare, you could make a fancy lambda for your remove_if
     auto notAlNumWithTolower = [] (char &c) {c = std::tolower(c); return !isalnum(c);};
     erase(remove_if(s.begin(),s.end(),notAlNumWithTolower),s.end());

This is not advised unless you need to optimize as it violates clean code principles. Feeling clever is a red flag for maintainability.
An alternative approach with a single loop and two index variables could reduce you down to one loop.
    bool isPalindrome2(const string &s) const{
        if(0 == s.size()) return true;
        for(size_t i=0u,j=s.size()-1;i<=j;++i,--j){
            //use while instead of if to handle multiple non-AN chars
            while(!isalnum(static_cast<unsigned char>(s[i]))&&(i<=j)) ++i;
            while(!isalnum(static_cast<unsigned char>(s[j]))&&(i<=j)) --j;
            if(j<i) break; //we shot past each other with non-AN chars, but last valid char passed
            if(tolower(s[i])!=tolower(s[j])) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

This is one loop, is not destructive, avoids copies, and avoids unnecessary calls to tolower() if it fails early. It requires a little more mental gymnastics to understand what is going on.
Thank you to commenters for catching degenerate cases and my silly use of remove_if
NOTE: the code provided is conforming to interface that OP defined and is assuming ascii as the OPs implementation relied on that assumption. there are some core guidelines on strings and how to use them more safely, those were not introduced here as to no complicate the issue of learning to do things without needless copies

What, if anything, should we make of the note posted at CppReference: "To use these functions [e.g. tolower] safely with plain chars (or signed chars), the argument should first be converted to unsigned char?" Should the OP cast the arguments to the functions of header <cctype> to unsigned char, as is done at CppReference?

I think your final solution has an issue if 2 non-alphanumeric characters are in a row. if(tolower(s[i])!=tolower(s[j])) return false; Think of the case where the string is  "##aa"  i would be incremented by 1. so the (tolower('#')!=tolower('a') condition would be true causing it to return false.

An empty string is a palindrome. What will your code return for an empty string input?

std::remove_if does not remove characters.  It returns an iterator to the start of the range of characters to remove.   Either you need to use erase on the returned iterator, or you use the returned iterator to limit how much of the string to process.

It looks like isPalindrome2 fails when s is "#". Subscripts i and j are both set to values outside of string s, and are then used in the third if-statement to index characters in string s.

@tbxfreeware So i added the casts, as the cppguidelines are correct that the specification does not require the implementations to do the right thing, but at least the two big one do.  And thank you for the degenerate string

@PaulMcKenzie thank you for calling out one of the things that I do a lot. my brain gets stuck in the whole why doesn't erase_if exists for everything.

@Macroft - Your edits look good. There is a new problem, however, with isPalindrome2. When s is the empty string, variable j is initialized to s.size() - 1. Because std::size_t is an unsigned type, variable j is effectively set to std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max().

@tbxfreeware Good catch.

For an empty input, loop will be executed and program is likely to crash due to out of bounds access in that loop. isPalindrome2 is also buggy.

The while loops in isPalindrome2 need to check whether the subscripts are in bounds, before calling std::isalnum. Compare with the similar loops in my answer above.

Yeah, I like your answer as it covers some stuff I rushed past and got things right the first time. I was just updating mine because it was different enough. can't comment on yours, but are you using the enums to do the math just to avoid magic numbers? or is the something subtle I am not catching?

I use the enums so that I can set the data type to std::size_t. That way, I don't have to double-check that the implicit conversions that would occur were I to use signed and unsigned integer types in the same expression will do the right thing. Fortunately, C++23 introduced new integer suffixes z and uz. I'll be switching to them ASAP.
